# How do I bulk download the past 100 days worth of EOD data for all stocks on Quandl with Python

Tags: python, api, stock, algorithmic-trading, quandl

Using the Quandl API and the Quandl Python library I'm attempting to do a bulk download of the past 100 days worth of EOD data.

The bulk download uses this call to download all EOD data for all tickers for the last collected day. Removing the download_type=partial parameter will download all historical EOD data:
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/EOD/data?download_type=partial

This call will download the last n day's worth of EOD for a single ticker:
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/AAPL?start_date=2019-02-07

Is it possible to combine these and download the last n day's worth of EOD data for all stocks at once?
At this point it seems my only options are:

1. Make individual API calls for all 8,000 tickers
2. Download all historical data for every stock

Comment: Do you have a link to the API docs? People without an account can't seem to access this API which makes helping you impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Quandle is not working for free anymore. used to be in the past.
If you want you can use IEX. check the below example which will give you the daily returns:

```
from datetime import datetime
from iexfinance.stocks import get_historical_data
from pandas_datareader import data
import pandas as pd
start =  '2014-01-01'
end = datetime.today().utcnow()

datasets_original_test = ['AAPL', 'MSFT','NFLX','FB','GS','TSLA','BAC','TWTR','COF','TOL','EA','PFE','MS','C','SKX','GLD','SPY','EEM','XLF','GDX','EWZ','QQQ','FXI','XOP','EFA','VXXB','HYG','XLI','XLU','JNK','USO','IWM','XLP','XLE','EWJ','XLK','KRE','XLV','VNQ','MBB','OIH','FEZ','RSX','EWG','SMH','TLT','IBB','SLV','IYR','XRT','XLB','EMB','AGG','INDA','EWW','DBO','SPLV','KBE','VGK','XLY','EWH','EWT','DIA','IVV','XLRE','EPI','IJR','IEF']
dataset_names_test = ['AAPL', 'MSFT','NFLX','FB','GS','TSLA','BAC','TWTR','COF','TOL','EA','PFE','MS','C','SKX','GLD','SPY','EEM','XLF','GDX','EWZ','QQQ','FXI','XOP','EFA','VXXB','HYG','XLI','XLU','JNK','USO','IWM','XLP','XLE','EWJ','XLK','KRE','XLV','VNQ','MBB','OIH','FEZ','RSX','EWG','SMH','TLT','IBB','SLV','IYR','XRT','XLB','EMB','AGG','INDA','EWW','DBO','SPLV','KBE','VGK','XLY','EWH','EWT','DIA','IVV','XLRE','EPI','IJR','IEF']

datasets_test = []
for d in datasets_original_test:
    data_original = data.DataReader(d, 'iex', start, end)
    data_original.index = pd.to_datetime(data_original.index, format='%Y/%m/%d')
    data_ch = data_original['close'].pct_change()
    datasets_test.append(data_ch)
df_returns = pd.concat(datasets_test, axis=1, join_axes=[datasets_test[0].index])
df_returns.columns = dataset_names_test
```